# Multidimensional array with string keys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I create a multidimensional array in c#?

I would like to assign values like this:

```
myArr["level1"]["enemy"][0] = 1;
myArr["level1"]["enemy"][1] = 4;

myArr["level1"]["friend"][0] = 2;
myArr["level1"]["friend"][1] = 3;
```

I can do the normal array using

```
public Array level1;
```

And push values to it.

But I can't seem to do the multidimensional one

Comment: Ordinary arrays are indexed by integers only, so something like `myArr["level1"]["enemy"][0] = 1` requires a custom indexer. See for example the `Dictionary<,>` class.

Comment: 1. This isn't javascript and probably shouldn't use datastructures like these. 2. Look at `Dictionary<string, T>` if you want something close to that. (https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

Comment: it can help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx https://www.dotnetperls.com/2d

Comment: Seems very difficult to manage and to setup - although it is an ok solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most similer thing you have in C# is a [`Dictionary`](http://dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys):

```
Dictionary<Person, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<Person, string>();
Person myPerson = new Person(); 
dictionary[myPerson] = "Some String";
...
string someString = dictionary[myPerson];
Console.WriteLine(someString); // "Some String"
```

You can take the Dictionary and builed some kind of Tuple structure as a key:

```
public class TwoKeyDictionary<K1,K2,V>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Pair<K1,K2>, V> _dict;

    public V this[K1 k1, K2 k2]
    {
        get { return _dict[new Pair(k1,k2)]; }
    }

    private struct Pair
    {
        public K1 First;
        public K2 Second;

        public override Int32 GetHashCode()
        {
            return First.GetHashCode() ^ Second.GetHashCode();
        }

        // ... Equals, ctor, etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I'll go with the Dictionary solution. However, If I wanted to use integers instead as key references, then how would I do this with a "normal" array structure: myArr[0][1] = {0,2,3} - myArr[0][1][0] = [1,4,5]? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You did :) Just easier to manage xml in my case. I have a 27x15 dimentional array, so keeping track of everything will be quite difficult using Dictionary solution. Thanks for answering.